# How do you run C# written on a Razor page from a button click with ASP.NET Core / Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I would like to execute a C# method that I wrote directly on the razor page when a button is clicked on the page. What I'm finding is if I have the reference to the button on the page, it executes the method on first load but never again when I actually click the button. Here's the code:

**Razor Page C# Reference:**

```
@functions
{
    int productIndex = 0;

    int AddProduct()
    {
        productIndex = productIndex + 1;
        return productIndex;
    }
}
```

**Button Reference:**

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="@AddProduct()" value="New Product" />
```

**I've also tried this reference and got the same result:**

```
<input class="btn btn-success" onclick="@AddProduct()" value="New Product"/>
```

Part 2 question that I have is how do you stop it from executing on page load so it only runs onclick? I've found references to `Page.IsPostBack)` but this isn't recognized on the client side, it seems.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191185/discussion-on-question-by-yecats-how-do-you-run-c-written-on-a-razor-page-from).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though at this point in time, *client-side C#* is in development (based off of the comments), and based solely off of the example you provided this is a pure JavaScript solution.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <button type="button" onclick="AddProduct()">New Product</button>
  
    <p id="ShowResult1">
  
    </p>
</div>
```

**jQuery/Javascript**

```
<script>
    var count = 0;

    function AddProduct() {
  
        count++;
  
        $("#ShowResult1").text(count);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: If OP doesn't like maintaining JavaScript for reasons like type safety etc, Typescript is also an option, though this is compiled into JavaScript anyway.

Comment: Important thing to note though is that C# runs on the server side and JavaScript runs on the client side.

Answer (score 8):

This is what I have done to implement C# code behind a button.

My button performs a post operation calling the function `OnPostGenerateWebName()` (the handler name for the button is `GenerateWebName`) so the button's post operation will look for and run the function named `OnPost<handler name>`:

First I created a button on the web page (`BusinessDetails.cshmtl` file):

```html
<button type="submit" asp-page-handler="GenerateWebName" class="btn btn-outline-info" 
id="btnGenerateWebName">Generate Business Web Name</button>
```

Next I create the handler `OnPostGenerateWebName` in C# (in the `BusinessDetails.cshtml.cs` file) which calls another C# function `CreateWebName()`:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostGenerateWebName(string returnUrl = null)
{
    CreateWebName();

    // all  done
    return Page();
}

private void CreateWebName()
{
    //generate a web name for this business
    if (Business.BusinessName.Length > 0)
    {
        var WebName = Business.BusinessName;
        // remove all special characters, only keep 0-9,a-z,A-Z
        WebName = Regex.Replace(Business.BusinessName, "[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", "");
        // set the new web name
        ModelState.Clear();
        Business.BusinessWebName = WebName;
    }
}
```

This function creates a web name from the business name and displays the web name on the form by setting the underlying class model element `Business.BusinessWebName`. In order for this to display on the form I had to call `ModelState.Clear()`.

Comment: I also had to add the following line to my .cshtml file:  

form asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post">

This enables the execution of the post function by the form button.

Answer (score 3):

I am using re-usable component which is the _Layout page. This makes the solution slightly more scalable, in my opinion.

What I have done is make a copy of _Layout, and renamed it _Layout2. The difference between _Layout and _Layout2 is literally just "bg-white" vs "bg-danger".

Now what is left is to bind buttons, links, inputs - however you like - to call _Layout, and _Layout2 respectively.

I have my HTML:

```html
@*This is on the Index.cshtml*@
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}
@*Div container to align my two buttons neatly*@
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        @*An option for styling - this one is the default Layout*@
        <div class="col">
            <form method="post">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="theme" value="_Layout">Blue!</button>
                @{Layout = Model.Message;}
            </form>
        </div>
        @*Another option - this one simply makes the navbar red*@
        <div class="col">
            <form method="post">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="theme" value="_Layout2">Red!</button>
                @{Layout = Model.Message;}
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, C# code to handle a POST - seeing as I am using buttons:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

    public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    public string Message { get; set; } = "_Layout";
    public void OnGet()
    {

    }
    public IActionResult OnPost(string theme)
    {
        Message = theme;
        return Page();
    }
}
```

This code will be called by the HTML I provided above and toggle between the two _Layout's - _Layout and _Layout2

(Only added an OnPost() method, and a Message property, the rest is boiler plate code when creating a fresh Razor Page)